# How do I stop my ipv6 address from changing in ubuntu

Tags: networking, 20.04

Whenever I move my wifi router a bit the ip address changes. I don't want my ip address to change because I have a server on that computer. How do I prevent my ipv6 address from changing in ubuntu ?

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu network configuration you need to disable DCHP for IPv6, and assign a static ipv6 address to the network interface.

To get more specific answer, you should add details to your question: your current network configuration, what software do you use to configure network.

Hint: if  you don't know what IP address to use, you can use the one your machine got from the router.

Comment: so how do I do it?

Comment: Tt depends on how you configure your network. If you use `netplan` here is the link: https://support.us.ovhcloud.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002296020-How-to-Configure-an-IPv6-Address-in-Ubuntu#18.04